# Rails mistakenly nesting called namespace into caller namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

`Bar` calls `Foo` and Rails thinks that `Foo` must be within the `Bar` namespace

```
module Foo
  class Lofatook
    def oops
      puts 'buckets of fun'
    end
  end
end
module Bar
  class Thedoor
    def theyhaveacavetroll
      Foo::Lofatook.new.oops
    end
  end
end
Bar::Thedoor.new.theyhaveacavetroll
```

This works fine as raw ruby. But when I put `Foo` in `lib/foo/lofatook.rb` and `Bar` in `app/models/bar/thedoor.rb` it throws this error:

```
uninitialized constant Bar::Foo
```

We are using the golden lib loading hammer of

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"] 
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

with all its glorious drawbacks.

But this should not mean it mistakenly assumes `Foo` must be part of `Bar`?

Comment: Not posting as an answer since it doesn't explain why this is happening (looks like it should work), but you could simply specify it as `::Foo::Lofatook` to make it clear that it's from the top-level namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was its not enough to have

```
module Foo
    class Lofatook
    end
end
```

in `lib/foo/lofatook.rb`. You must also have `lib/foo.rb`

```
module Foo
end
```

Thanks to @ma_il, using `::Foo::Lofatook` raised the error `uninitialized constant Foo` which pointed me in the right direction